# I have problem with snmp when i download it

Tags: apt

Here is the problem log while downloading the `snmp`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
snmp : Depends: libsnmp40 (=5.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.4) but 5.9.1+dfsg-ubuntu2.6 is to be installed
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`? Please include the output of those commands.

Comment: I am running those command and it's upgrade a bunch of things

Comment: Ensure that you have all three repositories enabled: `jammy`, `jammy-security`, `jammy-updates`. Then try again.